# Security exception in binding service in android from an activity in separate app mentioning permission denial

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-usb, android-securityexception

I have developed a bounded service app in android to get data from a Glucose meter device over USB serial port.I have developed another activity in a different app from where I am launching the service to get data in the activity screen.

I am getting following error when I am trying to install the activity app on my device

```
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager:  
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseui/.OmronGlucoseUIActivity } 
from null (pid=12170, uid=2000) requires android.hardware.usb.host
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at 
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at  
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at     


android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(
ActivityManagerNative.ja  va:2367)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at    
com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
 [2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at   
 com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at    
 com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
 [2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at 
 com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at  
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at   
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)
[2015-01-16 13:16:27 - OmronGlucoseUI] ActivityManager: at   
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have declared following permissions in  manifest files of both my activity and service app.

### This is the manifest file for my Service app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseservice"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseservice.OmronGlucoseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".GlucoseService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

         android:permission="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:stopWithTask="false" >

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseservice.GlucoseService" />
        </intent-filter>
         <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </service>
</application>
```

### This is the manifest file for my Activity app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseui"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseui.OmronGlucoseUIActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.hardware.usb.host">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
         <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have added

```
  android:permission="android.hardware.usb.host">
```

in both my apps.

When I am installing the service app first,it is getting installed
But then I am trying to install the activity app,and it is throwing the error

```
     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseui/.OmronGlucoseUIActivity } from null (pid=12170, uid=2000) requires android.hardware.usb.host
```

I am getting following error (in logcat) when I am trying to call

```
    bindService(intent,serviceconnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

from the activity

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.tcs.cto.omronglucoseservice.GlucoseService } without permission android.hardware.usb.host
```

I am not getting any solution from existing questions in this site.

Any answer to this question is appreciated.